# Зачеркнутый текст

Tags: android

Подскажите, как называется стиль зачеркнутого текста, мне надо его устанавливать в коде.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml("<s>" + YOUR_TEXT + "</s>");
```

Comment: спасибо =) я думаю есть еще вариант с setTypeface()

Answer (score 4):

Уверен, что есть еще варианты, но нашел пока такой вот

```
holder.title.setPaintFlags(holder.title.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```